# What should I put in build.gradle to set Idea's Project JDK?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I want to write `build.gradle` file in such a way that when other developers clone my project from GIT and import it in IntelliJ Idea, the Project JDK is set to 11 (so they don't have to set it manually). We don't commit any Idea configuration files to VCS.

It [seems](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) like Idea plugin for Gradle supports this, but I'm still unable to get it working.

Here's what I tried (**build.gradle**):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group = 'com.playground'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

idea {
    module {
        downloadSources = true
        jdkName = '11'
    }
}
```

And here's what I get on Idea -> New -> Project From Existing Sources -> Import Project From External Model (Gradle): **Project SDK is set to 1.8 even though I have JDK 11 installed.**

[image]